# Boost Current and Limit Voltage

Tags: esp8266, esp32, constant-current, buck-boost, constant-voltage

I have a radar gun which has a serial interface. The gun reports the velocity out to the serial port. I want to attach a microcontroller (ESP8266/ESP32) to the serial interface and forward the velocity somewhere else. One of the pins of the serial port also provides power which I'd like to use to power the microcontroller. It provides 6.6V and a max of 50mA.  The problem is that the microcontroller requires 5V and draws more than 250mA. To reduce the voltage, I have an LM2576 based module to step down the voltage. For the current, I've seen several low-cost modules which step up the current to anywhere from 1-2A. Can I combine these modules to achieve my power requirements? Are there any other considerations I should be aware of? Is there perhaps a better solution to this problem that still allows me to power the microcontroller from the radar gun as opposed to externally powering it?

Comment: What is the microcontroller going to do? There are plenty of low-power MCUs out there.  But, their processing power may not meet your needs.

Comment: You only have 0.33 watts available.  If your DC-DC converter is 100% efficient, it will provide at most 66 mA at 5 volts.  Think of the DC-DC converter  as passing power, not just voltage or current.

Comment: @Mattman944 The microcontroller needs to have wifi/bluetooth capabilities to send data over the air.

Comment: I have used low-power MSP430 processors extensively, but not Bluetooth. https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/swpt038/swpt038.pdf

Comment: @Mattman944 I found a BLE device that should work. The nRF52840 only draws like 10mA when transmitting.

Answer (score 1):

My respect you provided it looks like you will be power limited in your application. One thing that could be considered is using a different low power MCU that runs on Bluetooth as Bluetooth applications can get in the milliwatts range. Another thing that may work is a serial to Bluetooth module which you may be able to get in the power range you need.

Comment: Gotchya, I'll look around for one. Can you explain why the current booster along with the voltage booster wouldn't work?

Comment: You don't have enough power for the specs you have given, you can't create power out of thin air